# Temporary Easy Firewall

Tags: windows-10

When I am not in the range of any Wi-Fi, I need to connect my Windows 10 laptop with my mobile hotshot. But, the problem with this is that lots of background processes start using my costly 3G data.

I want a firewall program which should do this:

- A turn ON and turn OFF feature so that I should work normally when I am in Wi-Fi.
- When turned ON, it should disconnect all background processes by default.
- When turned ON, it should allow only those programs which are selected by me. e.g. Chrome.
- When turned OFF, my regular firewall should kick in.

Can you please suggest me such software?

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Firewall Control (WFC)](http://www.binisoft.org/wfc.php)

Its a much simpler front-end for the stock Windows Firewall (WF). Its a double-edged sword since disabling WFC also disabled WF. You can set it to default WF which is 'low filtering' mode.

- simple on/off toggle (I'd recommend using 'low filtering' mode for normal usage)
- what you're looking for sounds like 'high filtering'
- 'medium filtering', allowing whitelists
- again, I'd suggest standard 'low filtering' mode

I haven't tried WFC on W10 though, the site said it should work just fine.